# flink 1.3.1 elasticsearch 5.5.1. ElasticsearchSinkFunction fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I'm going through following samples using `Scala / sbt`:

[flink / elasticsearch / kibana](https://www.elastic.co/blog/building-real-time-dashboard-applications-with-apache-flink-elasticsearch-and-kibana)
[flink tutorial](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/connectors/PopularPlacesToES.scala)

My `built.sbt` includes following versions:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "22.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.10" % "1.2.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "5.5.1",
  "org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.5.1",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10" % "1.3.1"
)
```

Program fails with following exception (substract):

```
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.add(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ActionRequest;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessor;
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.BulkProcessorIndexer.add(BulkProcessorIndexer.java:52)
    at org.aj.flink.stream.TaxiDashboard$MyElasticsearchInserter.process(TaxiDashboard.scala:157)
    at org.aj.flink.stream.TaxiDashboard$MyElasticsearchInserter.process(TaxiDashboard.scala:137)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase.invoke(ElasticsearchSinkBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:575)
```

Here are my related imports:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch5.ElasticsearchSink
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchSinkFunction, RequestIndexer}
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest
import org.elasticsearch.client.Requests
```

Here is code for `MyElasticsearchInserter`:

```
  final class MyElasticsearchInserter(index: String, mappingType: String)
    extends ElasticsearchSinkFunction[(Int, Long, (Float, Float), Short)] {

    def process(element: (Int, Long, (Float, Float), Short),
                ctx: RuntimeContext,
                indexer: RequestIndexer): Unit = {

      // construct JSON document to index
      val json = Map(
        "time" -> element._2.toString,
        "location" -> (element._3._1 + "," + element._3._2),
        "cnt" -> element._4.toString
      )

      val rqst: IndexRequest = Requests.indexRequest
        .index(index)
        .`type`(mappingType)
        .source(json.asJava)
      indexer.add(rqst)
    }
  }
```

Here is code for adding a Sink:

```
if (writeToElasticsearch) {
  // write to Elasticsearch
  nycRides.addSink(new ElasticsearchSink(esConfig,
    esTransport, new MyElasticsearchInserter("nyc-idx", "popular-locations")))

}
```

It looks the question is rather if `flink 1.3.1` can be used with `elasticsearch 5.5.1`? Following method is not found?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.add(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ActionRequest;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessor;
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.BulkProcessorIndexer.add(BulkProcessorIndexer.java:52)
        at org.aj.flink.stream.TaxiDashboard$MyElasticsearchInserter.process(TaxiDashboard.scala:157)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently, Flink only supports ES 1.x and 2.x so far: https://flink.apache.org/ecosystem.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920543/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-in-flink)

Answer (score 0):

Just after a quick look at ES code base I think they removed that method(`BulkProcessor#add(ActionRequest)`) in `5.2.0`.

Flink uses that method internally. Unfortunately I fear Flink connector won't work with ES 5.3+ connector right now.