# Flink 1.3.1, Elasticsearch 2.4.6, RuntimeException: Elasticsearch client is not connected to any Elasticsearch nodes

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-flink

Trying to progress on Flink training / exersizes. Had following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555420/flink-1-3-1-elasticsearch-5-5-1-elasticsearchsinkfunction-fails-with-java-lang).
Re-installed Elasticsearch, now having version: **2.4.6**.
Elasticsearch seems to work. I'm able to access it via `http://localhost:9200`.
Created `index`, and `type mapping` as per exercise instructions using `cURL` commands.
Installed Kibana: **4.6.5**, and Kibana is able to connect to Elasticsearch and resolve the `index` I created.

Now, I try to execute `Flink` job, which reads data from Kafka topic, and attempts to populate the data into Elasticsearch, and, it fails to create a `Sink` with following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Elasticsearch client is not connected to any Elasticsearch nodes!
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch2.Elasticsearch2ApiCallBridge.createClient(Elasticsearch2ApiCallBridge.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase.open(ElasticsearchSinkBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Again, here is my `built.sbt` setting:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "22.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.10" % "1.3.1",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.10" % "1.3.1"
)
```

Imports:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchSinkFunction, RequestIndexer}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch2.ElasticsearchSink
```

And function which builds, and returns `Sink`.
Passed parameters `("localhost", 9300, "elasticsearch")`. Tried passing `"127.0.0.1"` for host, had the same error.

```
  private def getSink(host: String, port: Int, cluster: String) = {

    val config = Map(
      // This instructs the sink to emit after every element, otherwise they would be buffered
      "bulk.flush.max.actions" -> "1",
      // default cluster name
      "cluster.name" -> cluster
    )

    val jConfig: java.util.Map[String, String] = new java.util.HashMap()
    jConfig.putAll(config.asJava)

    println(s"jConfig: ${jConfig.toString()}")

    val transports = List(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port))
    val jTransports = new util.ArrayList(transports.asJava)

    println(s"jTransports: ${jTransports.toString()}")

    val esSink = new ElasticsearchSink(jConfig, jTransports,
      new MyElasticsearchInserter("nyc-idx", "popular-locations"))

    esSink
  }
```

Here is additional information from `Elasticsearch` log to indicate it's status:

```
...
...
[2017-08-08 20:12:24,203][INFO ][node                     ] [Beautiful Dreamer] stopping ...
[2017-08-08 20:12:27,063][INFO ][node                     ] [Beautiful Dreamer] stopped
[2017-08-08 20:12:27,066][INFO ][node                     ] [Beautiful Dreamer] closing ...
[2017-08-08 20:12:28,104][INFO ][node                     ] [Beautiful Dreamer] closed
[2017-08-08 20:21:58,212][INFO ][node                     ] [Aries] version[2.4.6], pid[1502], build[5376dca/2017-07-18T12:17:44Z]
[2017-08-08 20:21:58,264][INFO ][node                     ] [Aries] initializing ...
[2017-08-08 20:22:00,569][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Aries] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2017-08-08 20:22:00,857][INFO ][env                      ] [Aries] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [1.6gb], net total_space [45gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
[2017-08-08 20:22:00,857][INFO ][env                      ] [Aries] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-08-08 20:22:07,759][INFO ][node                     ] [Aries] initialized
[2017-08-08 20:22:07,759][INFO ][node                     ] [Aries] starting ...
[2017-08-08 20:22:08,179][INFO ][transport                ] [Aries] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-08-08 20:22:08,187][INFO ][discovery                ] [Aries] elasticsearch/_BFBmx-XR5aHFhbN9nvX2g
[2017-08-08 20:22:11,796][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Aries] new_master {Aries}{_BFBmx-XR5aHFhbN9nvX2g}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2017-08-08 20:22:12,415][INFO ][http                     ] [Aries] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-08-08 20:22:12,415][INFO ][node                     ] [Aries] started
[2017-08-08 20:22:12,654][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Aries] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2017-08-08 20:22:14,526][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Aries] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[nyc-places][1], [nyc-places][0]] ...]). ..
...
...
```

Going back to software versions used, it might not match exactly to the versions used by the training site.
Mine are Flink: **1.3.1**, and Elasticsearch: **2.4.6**.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was addressed by downgrading `Elasticsearch` installation to **2.3.5** version.
It was done to exactly match `Elasticsearch` [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.10/1.3.1) dependency following connector has:

```
"org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.10" % "1.3.1"
```